# Is it grammatically correct to say "education assistant" or "educational assistant"?

Tags: grammaticality

Which phrase is correct? Education assistant or educational assistant?

Comment: Per an answer (now deleted) that you provided, I have edited your question to change "dramatically" to "grammatically."

Answer (score 1):

Depending on context, either would be correct.

With *educational assistant*, it can be interpreted in two ways.

First:

> He works as an educational assistant.

This means that he works as an assistant in the field of education.

Second:

> She is a very educational assistant.

This means that she is an assistant in some field who is quite informative or helpful, one who relays knowledge.

But note how the construction of the sentence influences the meaning that is ascribed to the phrase.

Often, we do use an adjective in front of a noun:

- We say *legal assistant* and assume an assistant in the field of law—not an assistant who is law abiding.
- We say *civil engineer* and assume an engineer in the field of public works—not an engineer who is polite.

---

However, many job titles are formed by the combination of nouns.

Examples include *sanitation engineer*, *delivery person*, *post office worker*, *flight attendant*, and *massage therapist*.

---

I would say that both *education assistant* and *educational assistant* are grammatical.

To me, *educational assistant* sounds better, so long as the sentence construction makes it clear that—as a job title—it's using the right sense of the phrase.

Using Google Books NGram Viewer [suggests this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=educational%20assistant%2C%20education%20assistant&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceducational%20assistant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceducation%20assistant%3B%2Cc0) is an accurate assessment; however, I can't really point to it as "proof" because of the dual meaning of the phrase "educational assistant". Interestingly, if I use it to compare "as an educational assistant" with "as an education assistant," it [tells me](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as%20an%20educational%20assistant%2Cas%20an%20education%20assistant&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20an%20educational%20assistant%3B%2Cc0) that the second phrase doesn't appear often enough to even be graphed. (Note, though, that it does actually exist if you search Google books [directly](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=Q1rbW8jUNomG5wKkzaPIDQ&q=%22as%20an%20education%20assistant%22&oq=%22as%20an%20education%20assistant%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6973.7100.0.7382.2.2.0.0.0.0.77.147.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.77...33i10k1.0.W83jGFBoLoM).)

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion educational assistant is true because assistant is a noun so we should add an adj before it not a noun